# How to do inner join and group data while limiting related entry to 1 for each of the last two months?

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a list of all URLs from one table together with two ratings for each URL in second table. The problem is that one rating should be from current month (if it exists), the other rating should be from last month (also if it exists). Is that possible to achieve with MySQL? Both ratings should for each URL row be grouped into one cell.

Database would be populated with new values once or maybe multiple times per month.

Table structure and sample data:

```
urls 
id | url
1  | google.com
2  | apple.com
3  | bing.com

ratings 
id | rating | url_id | created_at 
1  | 10      | 1      | 2018-10-10
2  | 8       | 2      | 2018-10-10
3  | 11      | 1      | 2018-11-10
4  | 5       | 2      | 2018-11-10
5  | 6       | 3      | 2018-11-25
```

In the end my goal is to show a simple table of URLs and compare their ratings for each month.

```
url        | previous rating | current rating
google.com | 10              | 11 (rating has increased)
apple.com  | 8               | 5 (rating has decreased)
bing.com   | -               | 6
```

This is just a beginning of a query, I don't have idea how would I limit 2 ratings for each url as stated above?

```
SELECT 
    urls.id, 
    urls.url, 
    ratings.rating

FROM urls

INNER JOIN  ratings 
ON urls.id = ratings.url_id
```

Comment: Hint, join to the `ratings` twice, `INNER JOIN rating ratings_previous ... INNER JOIN rating rating_current...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want. I have assumed you would like to use the average rating for each month for comparison purposes.

```
SELECT u.url, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                 AND YEAR(r.created_at)  = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN rating END) AS `previous rating`,
       AVG(CASE WHEN MONTH(r.created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE())
                 AND YEAR(r.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN rating END) AS `current rating`
FROM urls u
LEFT JOIN ratings r
ON r.url_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.url
ORDER BY `current rating` DESC
```

Output:

```
url         previous rating     current rating
google.com  10.0000             11.0000
bing.com                        6.0000
apple.com   8.0000              5.0000
```

**Update**

To only use the last rating from each month (as requested in comments) is a little more complex. It can be done with two `JOIN`s to tables which contain the last rating for the previous and current months:

```
SELECT u.url,
       pr.rating AS `previous rating`,
       cr.rating AS `current rating`
FROM urls u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT url_id, rating
           FROM ratings r1
           WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at)
                               FROM ratings r2
                               WHERE r2.url_id = r1.url_id AND
                                   MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
                                   YEAR(created_at)  = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                               )
           ) pr ON pr.url_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT url_id, rating
           FROM ratings r1
           WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at)
                               FROM ratings r2
                               WHERE r2.url_id = r1.url_id
                               )
           ) cr ON cr.url_id = u.id
ORDER BY `current rating` DESC
```

[Updated demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2b3abade09b776f87aa9394fe6358c8)

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't need averages, just the single last value from current and last month. Hm how can I remove average? :)

Comment: @IvanTopić see my edit. The second query will give you the last rating for each month rather than the average. The updated demo includes both queries so you can compare results.